# how to fit model using loess gamm

Tags: model, gam, loess

I want to give an idea of variance using loess gamma. But fitting a model with my data gives me an error.

I have a response variable of insect count and treatment with four levels as the explanatory variable. The count was collected over time.

```
loess_model <- loess(ground_beetle ~ Treatment, span=0.4, data=m_data)
gg<-gamm(ground_beetle ~ lo(Treatment) + s(Sampling_date, k = 5, fx = 
T), family = poisson, data = m_data)

Error in loess(ground_beetle ~ Treatment, span = 0.4, data = m_data) : 
predictors must all be numeric
Error in names(dat) <- object$term :'names' attribute [1] must be the 
same length as the vector [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't with `gamm()`, nor with anything else from the *mgcv* package. `lo()` is from the *gam* package and these smoothes can't be combined with the penalised spline ideas from *mgcv*.

A more general problem and the proximate cause of the error with `loess()` is that you can smooth a factor variable such as `Treatment`. These two concepts are fundamentally incompatible.